# Spectrum of a ring (studied by Krull?) of rational functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $\mathbb A^2_k=\operatorname {Spec}k[x,y]$ the affine plane over $k$.
Consider the ring $R \subset k(x,y)$ of the rational functions on the plane defined and constant on $V(x)$ (the $y$-axis $x=0$).
What is $\operatorname {Spec}R$ ?
(This is the geometric translation of an example due, I think,  to Krull for which I unfortunately have no reference.)

**Edit**
Sorry,my definition of $R$ above is a bit ambiguous.
What I mean is that $R$ consists of those fractions $r(x,y)=\frac {p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}$ which can be written as the quotient of two polynomials $p(x,y),q(x,y)\in k[x,y]$ such that $q(0,y)\neq 0\in k[y]$ **and** $\frac {p(0,y)}{q(0,y)}\in k\subset k[y]$.
For example the rational function $\frac {y+x}{y-x}$ mentioned by @YCor in the comments **does** belong to $R$ since $y-0\neq0\in k[y]$ **and**  $\frac {y+0}{y-0}=1\in k \subset k[y]$

Comment: I understand that $\frac{y+x}{y-x}\notin R$, right? (it's constant on this $x=0$ axis but not "defined" at $(0,0)$).

Comment: If my understanding is correct, it's a local ring, with two obvious prime ideals, 0 and the maximal one (zero on the vertical axis). Further prime ideals are obtained by choosing a non-vertical line $D$, intersecting the vertical axis at $p$ and mapping $f\in R$ to its germ at $p$ on $D$.

Comment: Dear @YCor: Apologies for my ambiguous formulation. I have made an edit making what I meant more explicit, since I want the fraction you mention to belong to $R$

Comment: OK: so what remains from my previous comment is that this is a local ring with the two given prime ideals (0 and maximal), but I don't immediately see whether there are any others.

Comment: So just to clarify:  Your ring consists of all $\Big(cp(Y)+Xf(X,Y)\Big)/\Big(p(Y)+Xg(X,Y)\Big)$ such that $p(Y)\neq 0$ and $c\in k$.  Yes?

Comment: @Steven Landsburg: Yes, your representation of the elements of $R$ is efficient and absolutely correct.

Comment: In other words, the localization $A$ of $k[x, y]$ at the prime ideal $(x)$ is a discrete valuation ring with residue field $k(y)$. We are looking at the preimage of $k\subseteq k(y)$ in $A$. So you can consider the abstract setting: consider a dvr $A$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and a subfield $k \subseteq A/\mathfrak{m}$; what does the spectrum of the preimage of $k$ in $A$ look like?

Comment: Now your ring $R$ is seen to be the fiber product $A \times_{k(y)} k$. By Stacks Project, Tag 07RS https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07RS , $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is the pushout of $\operatorname{Spec} k \leftarrow \operatorname{Spec} k(y) \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ in the category of schemes.

Comment: It's not obvious to me however whether the underlying space of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is the pushout of the underlying spaces of the three affine schemes. That would make it homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} A$, i.e. two points, one in the closure of the other. That would agree with my inability to find prime ideals other than $(0)$, $(x)$.

Comment: I think that $R$ is a one-dimensional local domain with principal maximal ideal (and spectrum of cardinality $2$) . However it is not a DVR, because $x$ and $xy$ are in the maximal ideal but neither is divisible by the other. The only explanation for this strange result  would be  that $R$ is not noetherian.

Comment: Compare with the ring of all $f = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$ in $\mathbf{C}[[x]]$ with $a_0\in \mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: @lefuneste Maybe I'm mistaken, but what you wrote shows that the maximal ideal is NOT principal. Like in the example above, the maximal ideal is generated by the elements $ax$ with $a\in \mathbf{C}$ and you need infinitely many of those generators...

Comment: So the maximal ideal of $R$ is $xk[x,y]_{(x)}\cap R$, which is not equal to $xR$, in fact it is not finitely generated, because the system of generators $\{fx\,:\, f\in k(y)\}$ does not admit a finite generating subset. See my edit below.

Comment: Dear @Piotr: you write "Maybe I'm mistaken, but what you wrote shows that the maximal ideal is NOT principal" You are not mistaken at all and your fantastic comment explains  away all the problems I had with my erroneous belief that the maximal ideal was principal.  I can't thank you enough for this brilliant explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Completing my comments above to an answer. Probably one can simplify this quite a bit.)

**EDIT.** The previous version mistakenly identified the ideal $xA\cap R$ with $xR$. In fact, the maximal ideal $xA\cap R$ of $R$ is not finitely generated: it is generated by $\{xf\,:f\in k(y)\}$ and a finite subset does not suffice. Similarly, $xR$ is not a prime ideal: we have $xy^{-1}, xy\notin xR$ but their product $x^2\in xR$.

The ring has exactly two prime ideals, $(0)\subseteq \mathfrak{m}$ where $\mathfrak{m} = A\cap xk[x,y]$.

Let $A = k[x, y]_{(x)}$ is the local ring at the generic point of the $y$-axis. This is a discrete valuation ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(x)$ and residue field $A/\mathfrak{m} = k(y)$.

The ring $R$ in question is the preimage of $k\subseteq k(y)= A/\mathfrak{m}$ in $A$. In other words, it is the fiber product $R = A\times_{A/\mathfrak{m}} k$.

**EDIT** (following Anton's comment below): a better reference for the following two paragraphs is stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0D2G Lemma 0B7J: the underlying space of the spectrum of the fiber product of the form $A\times_{A/I} B$ is the pushout of the corresponding underlying topological spaces of spectra.

By Stacks Project, Tag 07RS https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07RS, $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is the pushout of $\operatorname{Spec}k \leftarrow \operatorname{Spec} A/\mathfrak{m} \to \operatorname{Spec} A$.

By Theorem 3.4 (and its proof) in Schwede's paper [http://www-personal.umich.edu/~kschwede/SchemeWithoutPoints.pdf](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ekschwede/SchemeWithoutPoints.pdf) , we get that the underlying space of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is the corresponding pushout in spaces. But $\operatorname{Spec} A/\mathfrak{m}\to \operatorname{Spec} k$ is a homeomorphism, and hence so is $\operatorname{Spec} A\to \operatorname{Spec} R$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this fine answer.

Comment: Thanks again, Piotr: your quite subtle Edit perfectly explains why I was uneasy with my calculations, which prompted me to post the question in the first place. (By the way, are you of Russian origin as your first name seems to indicate?)

Comment: There is no mistake if you don't forget to take the radical: $rad(xR)=xA$, because $(Ax)^2\subset x(Ax)\subset xR$. By the way, $Ax\subset R$, so you don't need the intersection in $Ax\cap R$.

Comment: I think a better reference is https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0D2G Lemma 15.6.2

Comment: @AntonMellit perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your ring $A$ is a pullback

$$\matrix{
A&\rightarrow & k\cr
\downarrow &&\downarrow\cr
k[X,Y]_{(X)}&\rightarrow& k(Y)\cr}$$

where the right arrows send $X$ to zero.

If you invert $X$, the fields on the right become $0$, so the downarrow on the left becomes an isomorphism $A[X^{-1}]=k(X,Y)$.  Thus all nonzero primes in $A$ contain $X$.

If you go mod $X$, $A$ becomes the field $k(Y)$.  Thus $(X)$ is maximal. Because it is contained in all nonzero primes, it is the only nonzero prime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this fine answer.

Comment: Very similar to my answer, and with the same mistake: $(X)$ is not a prime ideal, since $XY$ and $XY^{-1}$ are not in $(X)$ but their product is. The correct ideal is $Xk[X,Y]_{(X)}\cap A$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger:  Yes, I think our answers were about 12 seconds apart.  (Actually you beat me by a little more than that with your comments, which were posted while I was composing my answer.)  Thanks for the correction; I'll leave the answer and your comment in place.

Comment: Are you implicitly using some property of fiber products and localisations?

Comment: @AntonMellit :  I am using only that localization is exact, hence preserves pullbacks.

Comment: Ah you view this pullback in the category of modules, where indeed we can use that localization is exact. Nice! It didn't appear to me that pullback of rings is in particular pullback of modules.

Comment: @AntonMellit :  "Ah you view this pullback in the category of modules, where indeed we can use that localization is exact".  Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

I will join the party if you don't mind.

Let $A=k[x,y]_{(x)}$. This is the ring of fractions $p/q$ such that $q$ is not divisible by $x$. Our ring $R$ can be written as $R=k+x A$.

Inverting $x$ produces $R[x^{-1}] = A[x^{-1}]=k(x,y)$. The latter is a field with a unique prime ideal $(0)$. Thus the only prime ideal not containing $x$ is $(0)$.

The radical of $(x)$ is $x A$ because $(x A)^2 \subset x ( x A) \subset x R$ implies $xA\subset \sqrt{(x)}$ and $x A$ is maximal. So the only prime ideal containing $x$ is $x A$.

Any prime ideal either contains $x$ or it doesn't, so $(0), xA$ is the complete list.